# Can the weak convergence imply the strong convergence in local sense?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

If $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$, and $Q$ is a function with exponential decay, then how can we deduce that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} Q^2f_n^2 dx \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} Q^2 f^2 dx
\end{equation}
after extracting a subsequenece if necessary. It is very easy to check that when it is very far away from origin, by the pointwise decay of $Q$ and the uniformly boundedness of $f_n$ in $L^2$, we can get the smallness for $|x| \ge R \gg1$, and thus it remains us to check that the convergence in bounded domain $|x| \le R$. And I guess $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ for any fixed $\Omega \subset \subset \mathbb{R}^3$  compact set. But I have no idea about it.

Comment: You do get $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, for a subsequence, since the embedding of $H^1(\Omega)$ into $L^2(\Omega)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

The weak convergence on the whole domain do not imply the strong one in a compact set.

Take for example a Fourier basis $f_n$ of $L^2(B_1(0))$ multplied for the indicator function of $B_1(0)$.

1. $\|f_n-f_m\|_2=1$ for every $n\neq m$
2. $f_n$ converges weakly to $0$
3. every $f_n$ as compact support, thus is unaffected by functions with rapid decay

Comment: yes, your counterexample is right, and I have read the problem again, and I noticed that the condition $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^2$ maybe not enough, and thus I change into a stronger condition $f_n \to f$ weakly in $H^1$. Then I wonder if $(Q^2,f_n^2) \to (Q^2,f^2)$ strongly?